# jQuery follow hyperlink with a target="_blank"

Tags: jquery

I am trying to open a hyperlink with target="blank".

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    $('a').click();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Report</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a normal target="_blank" hyperlink to page2 and had page2 do the database processing.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the trigger events only fire events that have been linked using jQuery.  Look at this modified example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
        alert('adf');
    });
    $('a').click();
});
```

Comment: Hmm.  That's weird.  Maybe what I'm wanting is a feature that has been exploited by hackers, so is no longer allowable.
As the page loads, I need it to load another page on top of it like target="_blank"

Answer (score 2):

`click()` creates an on-click event and attaches it to the object. It doesn't actually *cause* a click, it just creates a function that executes after a user's click if/when they choose to do so.

What you're looking for is `trigger()`, which lets you simulate a click without the user actually initiating it. Also, you should the `ready` event instead of the `load` event in most cases.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).ready(function() {
    $('a').trigger('click');
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Report</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Another thing to note - what you're trying to do may be blocked by popup blockers, as they're designed to stop a website from opening a new window when the page is loaded.

Comment: Actually click() does fire a click event just like trigger.  It only register an event handler if you pass it an argument.  Check out the jquery docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click

Comment: I read the docs.jquery.com page you referred to, but there was no example of how the cick event was used.

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz, but this still isn't working.
jQuery(function($) {
    $('a').trigger('click');
});

Comment: Its the first listing, the one without any parameters.

Comment: @psenn Sounds like you're running into a popup blocker or something, then. The only other thing I can suggest right now is to give the link an ID and access it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Click, according to the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click),

> "Causes all of the functions that have
>   been bound to that click event to be
>   executed."

This would not include opening the link.

I'm not sure how one would do it otherwise. In fact I'm fairly certain that it cannot be done.